How to create instance of traci for sumo in C++
So,basically I am working on the open source code of the sumo eclipse and I want to use Traci library for real time simulation so for that I included the TraCIAPI.h file and also included the path in CMakeLists.txt after including and then I build and make it no error is coming but after I try to make an instance of that i.e. "TraCIAPI traci; then error is coming
So basically I'm expecting that it should include the traci library so that I can use it functions for real time simulation

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist. Also please learn how to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to improve it.
